# Does Raspberry Pi Camera use specific GPIO pins?

Tags: pi-4, camera, raspi-config, config.txt

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. Certain pins are used by some sensors. Once I plug my sensors into my system, the camera cannot be found by the Raspberry, on the other hand, everything works fine when I unplug my devices. I tried disabling and then re-enabling the Camera Interface. Didn't work.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

Additionally,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o test3.jpg
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

[image: Raspi PinOut -- Highlighted pins mean that it is used.]

What could be the issue here? I wonder whether the Raspberry Pi Camera port has a connection to one of the GPIO pins in its scheme or anything similar. If so, is it possible to migrate those pins by editing /boot/config.txt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You plug in sensors.  Plug in one by one until the camera fails.  Which sensor causes the problem?  **Please edit the information into your question.**

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible at this moment. All sensors are already soldered and I can only un/plug them all at once via an external pin.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The camera uses a number of GPIO pins, but not those on the expansion header.

This is poorly documented, but it also appears to use an I²C interface - almost certainly the **reserved** interface on pins 27,28 which should NOT be used for anything except HATs.

Comment: I also knew the same but since I don’t use them, it shouldn’t be a problem for me though. It is weird. Is there anything possible other than this?

Answer (score 0):

@milliways is correct. connecting GPIO0,1 (pins 27/28) to anything yields a strange error in picamera2. The error does not give any indication of the cause, hence I list it here so search-engines might find it.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
Exception ignored in: <function Picamera2.__del__ at 0x7f76fea5c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 404, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 604, in close
    if self._preview:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Picamera2' object has no attribute '_preview'
```